# What's the English equivalent of the Hindi word फेंकना (fenkna)?

Tags: single-word-requests

In Hindi, the word फेंकना (fenkna) describe an act of boasting in a way that  is obviously untrue and ridiculous. It might be me bragging about swimming twenty miles few years ago. If you know me, and the fact that I lack any athletic experience, it would be easy to infer that the claim is plain absurd.

The word literally means "to throw", but its use that way is quite popular.

The closest word that comes to mind is "bullshiting", but I wanted to know if there's a more formal one to describe this action.

Comment: I'm thinking on *bluffing* and synonyms but this might not be 100% suitable as *bluffing* doesn't imply boasting

Comment: Perhaps braggadocio?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would like to use it in a sentence?

Comment: It’s not boasting at all, it’s just the normal imparting of alternative facts.  :-(

Comment: @psosuna Bluffing/faking is the right answer, You should consider putting it as answer. Bragging or boasting is type of bluffing which only exhibiting self-importance, while "fekna" encompasses not just bragging/boasting but frivolous lying. E.g. 1) He was Bluffing (Fekraha hai) about the details of the report. E.g 2) All the people in the room knew that XYZ was bluffing (Fekraha hai) about his new Ferrari. While the first example is about faking details, second example is about bragging but both are bluff (fekna)

Answer (score 0):

> **[rodomontade](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rodomontade?a=british)** noun (formal): ​
>
> talk or behaviour that is boastful (= praising yourself too much) or exaggerated (= making
>   something seem bigger or more important than it really is):
>
> *The President's boastful rodomontade was parodied abroad.*

([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rodomontade?a=british))

Edit. It originates from the French, and is usually written, whether in verb, noun or adjectival form with a capital letter, based as it is on an *extended use of Rodomonte, the name of a courageous, but hot-tempered and boastful Saracen leader, one of the characters in the epic poem Orlando innamorato by M. M. Boiardo (1495) and its continuation by L. Ariosto, Orlando furioso (1532).* (OED).

Comment: Excellent. I have added a word about etymology.

Answer (score 0):

Examples, for braggadocio, as suggested by @Faheem-Mitha:

> 1 a : empty boasting
>
> his braggadocio hid the fact that he felt personally inadequate

([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/braggadocio))

> great confidence that someone expresses in their own abilities and qualities:
>
> For all his braggadocio, he must have had moments of doubt.

([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/braggadocio))